# Alternative Definition of Contravariant Functor

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Given two categories, $C$ and $D$, a covariant functor is usually defined as a regular functor $C \to D$, whereas a contravariant functor is usually defined as a regular functor $C^{op} \to D$.

> **Question:** Could we also define a contravariant functor (equivalently) as a functor $C \to D^{op}$?
>
> Or is there an isomorphic natural transformation between functors $C \to D^{op}$ and $C^{op} \to D$?

I am trying to think of what the difference would be (if any).

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: A functor $F: C \to D^{op}$ is equivalent to a functor $C^{op} \to D$ by taking the opposite since $F^{op}: C^{op} \to (D^{op})^{op}$ is a functor to $D$.

I'd say it is easier to work with functors $C^{op} \to D$ as opposed to functors $C \to D^{op}$. A natural transformation $\sigma: F \Rightarrow G: C \to D^{op}$ has components $\sigma_c \in D^{op}(Fc,Gc)$, which are basically arrows $Gc \to Fc$. By working with the corresponding functors $C^{op} \to D$ from the beginning, you don't have to turn around these components later on.

Comment: Also, contravariant functors with an opposite category as the domain arise more naturally. For example, the hom-functor $C^{op}\times C \to \mathbf{Set}$ restricts to a functor $C^{op}\to \mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: You could, but then you'd have to annoyingly dualize statements of various theorems about computing covariant functors before they'd apply to contravariant functors. That is why $C^{op}\to D$ is the "correct" way to present a contravariant functor as a covariant functor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, both formulations are equivalent. Let's see the correspondence.

Let's see that giving a contravariant functor $F:C^{op}\to D$ is equivalent to giving another functor $G:C\to D^{op}$.

Assume we know $F$. At the level of objects it's clear what to do: for any $a\in Ob(C)=Ob(C^{op})$ we define $G(a):=F(a)\in Ob(D^{op})=Ob(D)$.

Now, given any arrow $g\in\hom_C(a,b)=\hom_{C^{op}}(b,a)$, note that $\hom_D(F(b),F(a))=\hom_{D^{op}}(F(a),F(b))$, so we may regard $F(g)$ as an element of $\hom_{D^{op}}(F(a),F(b))$ via this identification, therefore we can define $G(g)=F(g)$. Clearly $G$ is a functor since $F$ is.

The other equivalence is pretty similar, so I'll let you do it.